# how to do this through collections

Tags: java, collections

There are two classes `Product` and     `DeliveryAddress`.

I try to prepare a unique list of Pincodes and Sum of product price delivered in each Pincode.
Can some body tell me how ?

```
class Product {  
    String name;
    String category;
    int price;
    //Getter/Setters
}    
    
class DeliveryAddress{   
    String ProductName;
    String Address;
    String Pincode;
    //Getter/Setters
}

 

Input is List<Product> productList
Input is List<DeliveryAddress> deliveryAddressList
```

Comment: Write out how you’d do it in pseudo code. For example “for each address I would find the product that matches the product name and then …”.

Comment: Hi Lajos Arpad,  thanks for your answer. i could not understand how this line of code "pinMap.put(da.getPincode(), pinMap.getOrDefault(da.getPincode(), 0) + p.getPrice());" works

Answer (score 0):

Something like this ought to work

```java
public Map<String, Integer> totalByPincode(final  List<Product> productList, final List<DeliveryAddress> deliveryAddressList) {
    final Map<String, Product> productByName = productList.stream()
            .collect(toMap(Product::getName, identity()));

    return deliveryAddressList.stream().collect(groupingBy(
            DeliveryAddress::getPincode,
            mapping(
                    address -> productByName.get(address.getProductName()),
                    summingInt(Product::getPrice))));
}
```

i.e.

1. Index your products by `name`
2. Loop over your addresses, group them by `pinCode`
3. Transform each address to a `Product` by looking up the `name` in the index created earlier
4. Sum the prices of the products.

Answer (score 0):

Simple. You need to have two loops, one of the loops embedded into the other and fill a `Map`:

```
Map<String, Integer> pinMap = new HashMap<String, Integer>();
for (int addressIndex = 0; addressIndex < deliveryAddressList.size(); addressIndex++) {
    for (int productIndex = 0; productIndex < productList.size(); productIndex++) {
        DeliveryAddress da = deliveryAddressList.get(addressIndex);
        Product p = productList.get(productIndex);
        if (da.ProductName.equals(p.name)) pinMap.put(da.PinCode, pinMap.getOrDefault(da.PinCode, 0) + p.price);
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi Lajos Arpad,  thanks for your answer. i could not understand how this line of code "pinMap.put(da.getPincode(), pinMap.getOrDefault(da.getPincode(), 0) + p.getPrice());" works

Comment: Looping over a `List` by index is a bit of an antipattern…

Comment: @SKM.CODER first let's understand `pinMap.getOrDefault(da.getPincode(), 0)`. This loads the map value by pin code if exists and defaults to 0 if it does not exist. Basically we add some value to the already existent value. If the value did not exist, then we initialize it with 0. We add p.getPrice() to it, that is, if there was no value so far for that pin code, then we add p.getPrice() to 0, the default value. If there was a value that's greater than 0, then we add the price to that already existing value.

Comment: @SKM.CODER now that we have clarified getOrDefault, we know that `put` will (re)place da.PinCode with the sum of the already existing value (or 0 if such a value did not exist yet) and price.